# Underlying Objective-C module not found for target Framework

Tags: swift, xcode, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to create a framework that has a dependency to an external library (cordova). The framework is mainly in Objective-C with some Swift 3.x files (cordova plugins) and the linked external library in objective-C.

I have created an **Umbrella header** in order to avoid the **bridging-header** error for frameworks. I have also created a **module.modulemap** in order for the swift files to have access to the external Objective-C library (cordova).

This setup used to work when in Swift 2.3 and compile with no problems. After a recent xCode update, Swift 3.x is mandatory so I updated all the swift files to the latest version. After this update, all my swift files seem to not have access to the objective-c files, also located in the same project/target.

Now I'm getting the `Underlying Objective-C module <moduleName> not found` Error and a lot of `Use of Undeclared type` error messages.

Comment: Try renaming the `module.modulemap` to `nameofthemodule.modulemap`

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, renaming `module.modulemap` to `nameofthemodule.modulemap` fixed the problem.